# What is the most efficient alternative to LinkedHashSet to retrieve an element?

Tags: java

There is an existing functionality that uses LinkedHashSet to store a set of unique element besides preserving the insertion order.

There is a new requirement that requires to retrieve a specific element if it already exists in the LinkedHashSet. i.e. when trying to add an element, the method should check if the element already exists and return the existing element. There may be up to 10000 elements in the LinkedHashSet.

Current way to achieve this is by using an iterator on the LinkedHashSet

```
Class CustomObject {
    String id;
    String name;

    CustomObject (String id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    }

    LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashSet<CustomObject>> parentRecord = new LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashSet<CustomObject>>(4);
    .
    .
    .
    public CustomObject addCustomObject (CustomObject customObject) 
    //Assume the following child node not to be null
        Set<CustomObject> child = parentRecord.get("customObjectName");

        if (child.contains(customObject)) {         
            Iterator<CustomObject> it = child.iterator();       
            while (it.hasNext()) {
               CustomObject node = it.next();           
                   if (node.getId().equals(customObject.getId())) {
                       return node;
                   } 
            }   
        }

        child.add(customObject);

        return customObject;
    }

}
```

Is there an efficient alternative data structure way that will

1. Store unique values
2. Return specific element if it already exists when trying to add
3. Preserve insertion order (if possible)

> Since the customObject being added is already in the set, returning
>   the customObject itself makes sense.However, that somehow doesnt work hence went for 
>   iterator as I am building nodes within nodes. The customObject returned may have child 
>   nodes.

Comment: Semantically, if a `Set.contains(object)` returns true, you already have the stored element (or an equivalent instance) - its the parameter of `contains()`! Therefore it doesn't make sense to `get()` a specific element from a Set. A Map seems to be a better fit for what you want to achieve, as it can map an immutable identifier to a certain state or instance of an entity.

Comment: (Note: the code above won't compile. The `return child;` statement returns a value with the wrong type.  It should be `return customObject;`)

Comment: well caught, corrected the code now ;-)

Comment: I think, based on what I see in the code, that you don't want to check to see if _the object_ already exists in the `Set`, you want to check if an object with _the same Id_ exists in the `Set`. Is that correct? If so, the answers you have so far may not perform correctly in all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `LinkedHashMap<CustomObject, CustomObject>` instead of the `LinkedHashSet<CustomObject>`.

(This assumes that `CustomObject.equals` and `CustomObject.hashcode` use your current "matching" method.  Otherwise use a 3rd-party alternative with an external "hasher" ...)

The method becomes:

```
public CustomObject addCustomObject (CustomObject customObject) {
    Map<CustomObject, Custom> child = parentRecord.get("customObjectName");

    res = child.get(customObject);
    if (res == null) {   
        child.put(customObject, customObject);
        return customObject;
    } else {
        return res;
    }
}
```

That should all be `O(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

A `LinkedHashMap` is the `Map` equivalent of `LinkedHashSet`.  If will give you insertion order traversal, guarantee uniqueness of keys and also give you constant time lookup of items in the `Map`.  This might be an alternative for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `contains()`. It is specified to be O(1).

Comment: get() method is not available on LinkedHashSet!

Comment: Err, oops, I meant `contains()`!

Comment: it should return me the actual element, not just check if it exists ;-)

Comment: I don't get this. If you already have the element that already exists (i.e. you just tried adding it, and it failed), why not just return that? Why would you want to (much less need to) bother going through all the trouble of getting it from the Set?

Comment: That somehow didnt work hence went for iterator. Surprisingly, the hashcode returned by customObject (object being added) and node (returned by the iterator) is the same and still returning the customObject doesnt work.Investigating!

Comment: @MikkelLøkke The application is to make a "probe" object that responds to equals() and hashCode() just like the object being searched for, but doesn't contain all the same information. It's basically like a key.

Comment: @StefanReich That doesn't really make sense either. If you want to use a Map, you should use a Map, not a Set.

Comment: @MikkelLøkke No, you can use a set, there are applications for it. It's more compact (if you have a better set implementation). Nice to continue a talk from 9 years ago BTW :-D

Comment: @MikkelLøkke Here's an example of what I am talking about: http://code.botcompany.de/1013079 It's a bit on the nonsensical side as the class X doesn't carry any information beyond the key field (which is called "value" for additional confusion) - but it could, and that is the point (getting away with a pointer to a single object instead of a pointer for key and value each like you would need in a Map). Splitting the pointer count in half is a huge deal if you store like millions of objects (I've done that in an AI project).

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood the question. the `LinkedHashSet` works for your requirement just fine.

But I assume that you have **already implemented `equals() and hashcode()` in your `CustomerObject` correctly.**

so:

> Store unique values

Set has that feature for you.

> Return specific element if it already exists when trying to add

with your equals and hashcode method, just do

```
if (set.contains(obj)) "return" obj;
```

the "return" above is not return statement in your method,  means if contains true, just take the object you want to do insert. because it equals the obj in set. (dont have to iterate the Set and get the equaled object)

And `contains(obj)` takes `O(1)`, due to the hashtable.

> Preserve insertion order (if possible)

`linkedhashSet` based on `linkedList`, so insertion order is preserved.

Comment: Since the customObject being added is already in the set, returning the customObject itself makes sense.However, that somehow doesnt work because I am building nodes within nodes. The customObject returned may have child nodes. Kinda a peculiar requirement. But your answer was useful! cant vote up, I am a newbie.

Comment: @Giri, the children should be checked in your equals method. the question is "how do you define equal".

Comment: `@Override
    public boolean equals (Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
 if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        CustomObject that = (CustomObject) o;
        return !(id != null ? !id.equals(that.id) : that.id != null);
    }`